# How do I calculate amount of time in each week between two dates - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

[EDITED TO SIMPLIFY]

I have 500+ records. All of which have a reference number, a start date, an end date and a total machining time.

```
Ref    StartDate    EndDate    MachineTimeHours
123    24/01/2020   30/01/2020   28
321    25/02/2020   27/02/2020   18
```

Starting at the start date, I need to calculate how many machining hours fall into 1 week and how many fall into the next.
Our working days are Monday to Thursday 8 Hours & Friday 4 Hours.

Ref 321 has a start of 25/2 which is a Tuesday and a finish date of 27/2 which is a Thursday in the same week. This will calculate as all 18 hours being in the same week. 
Ref 123 has a start of 24/01. This is a Friday in Week 4 of 2020.
Based on my rules, that would be 4 hours in week 4 and 24 Hours in week 5.

I have a table called 'DatesList' which has all days on it (as well as week number and working hours).

I need my table to list each record for each week and I'll do the grouping on a separate report.

In effect I'd like

```
Ref    StartDate    EndDate    MachineTimeHours   Week   Hours
123    24/01/2020   30/01/2020   28                4       4
123    24/01/2020   30/01/2020   28                5       24 
321    25/02/2020   27/02/2020   18                9       18
```

Comment: Where does percentage come into the picture?

Comment: Create / generate a calendar table with  working hours once. Use it in the queries.

Comment: A calendar table as suggested by @Serg is the way to go here. Anything else is just a work around that will mostly work most of the time. Your calendar table would have the number of working hours for each day and includes holidays and any other anomalies to the normal schedule.

Comment: @SeanLange I have a table called 'dateslist' and it has every day for the last 2 years and next 3 years. it also has a week number. I need to figure out how to calculate how much of it the total machining hours for a job, falls in one week and how much of it falls in the other, by only having a start date and an end date.

Comment: If you could provide a [mcve] myself and many others can make short of this. But with no tables, data or desired output it is too much effort on my part.

Comment: @SeanLange There is a table and desired output on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with creating some reference tables.

For the example those are just temporary tables.

**Reference data:**

```
--
-- Reference tables
-- 
CREATE TABLE #ref_calendar
(
   CalDate DATE PRIMARY KEY,
   DayOfWeek SMALLINT NOT NULL,
   WeekNr SMALLINT NOT NULL,
   IsHoliday BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

DECLARE @year int = 2020;
SET DATEFIRST 1; -- 1: monday start

;WITH RCTE_DATES AS
(
  SELECT 
  DATEFROMPARTS(@year, 1, 1) AS caldate

  UNION ALL

  SELECT dateadd(day, 1, caldate)
  FROM RCTE_DATES
  WHERE caldate <= DATEFROMPARTS(@year, 12, 31)
)
INSERT INTO #ref_calendar (CalDate, DayOfWeek, WeekNr)
SELECT 
caldate, 
DATEPART(weekday, caldate) AS DayOfWeek,
DATEPART(week, caldate) AS WeekNr
FROM rcte_dates c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM #ref_calendar ref
  WHERE ref.CalDate = c.caldate
)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 366);

CREATE TABLE #ref_workhours
(
  Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  DayOfWeek SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  WorkHours DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
  ActiveFrom DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT GetDate(),
  ActiveTill DATE
);

INSERT INTO #ref_workhours 
(DayOfWeek, WorkHours) VALUES
 (1, 8.0), (2, 8.0), (3, 8.0), (4, 8.0), (5, 4.0),
 (6, 0), (7, 0);
```

**Some sample data:**

```
--
-- Sample data
--
CREATE TABLE YourDateRangeTable
(  
  Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  JobNumber INT NOT NULL,
  PartNumber VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  Machine CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  StartDate DATE NOT NULL, 
  EndDate DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO YourDateRangeTable 
(JobNumber, PartNumber, Machine, StartDate, EndDate) values 
(12345, 'XYZ321', 'DL8', '2020-01-24', '2020-01-30');
```

Then you can run a query that uses the reference tables.

```
SELECT JobNumber, PartNumber, Machine
, YEAR(cal.CalDate) AS [Year]
, cal.WeekNr AS [Week]
, SUM(w.WorkHours) AS [Hours]
FROM YourDateRangeTable t
JOIN #ref_calendar cal
  ON cal.CalDate >= t.StartDate 
 AND cal.CalDate < t.EndDate
JOIN #ref_workhours w
  ON w.DayOfWeek = cal.DayOfWeek
GROUP BY JobNumber, PartNumber, Machine
, YEAR(cal.CalDate), cal.WeekNr;
```

**Returns:**

```
JobNumber   PartNumber  Machine     Year    Week    Hours
12345       XYZ321      DL8         2020        4   4.00
12345       XYZ321      DL8         2020        5   24.00
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3aa03f8082501293bbb133891090f2a3)*

Comment: Appreciate this Luk but it doesn't give me what I need. I've got the total hours for each part and how long it takes. I need to calculate how much of the time falls into one week and how much falls into the other.

Comment: @David Updated, the weeknr is now included in ref_calendar. So it can be used to group on. And sample data has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the detes of two given date and also weeknumber and a case statement for the working hour. Based on the result from the inner query write an outer query which will give the sum of total working hour.

Here is the given query.

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '20200124',
        @MaxDate DATE = '20200130'

--Fri Week 4 = 4 hours
--Mon Week 5 = 8 hours
--Tue Week 5 = 8 hours
--Wed Week 5 = 8 hours

Select WeekNo, SUM(WorkingHour) as TotalWorkingHour from(
Select [DATE], DATEPART(WEEK, [DATE]) - DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM,0,[DATE]), 0))+ 1 as WeekNo,
    DATENAME(weekday, [DATE]) as WeekDay, Case DATENAME(weekday, [DATE])
when 'Friday' then 4 
when 'Monday' then 8
when 'Tuesday' then 8
when 'Wednesday' then 8
else 0
end as WorkingHour from(
SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b
)a
)b group by WeekNo
```

It will give the result as below:

```
WeekNo  TotalWorkingHour
------------------------
4        4
5        24
```

You can find the demo [Here](https://rextester.com/FFDU15208).

Comment: Hi Suraj, I don't think this is quite what I need, though it isn't far away. I need to calculate it based on hundreds of records that all have a start date and a finish date. Each of them has a total machining time and I need to figure out how much of that machining time falls in one week and how much of it the next.

Comment: @David As per what you have stated in comment I want to say that if different dates are in the table, then you can create two variable and assign it to the minimum and maximum data. After that you can join the table where machine id is available. To get the total machine wise you can pass machine id in the group by also.